# google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase - strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have project with 4 modules:

- app (main)
- common-lib
- C
- D

I have correctly set firebase as states here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

In my **app module** I don't use any additional libraries, only module dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile project(path: ':common-lib', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':common-lib', configuration: 'release')
}
```

In my **common-lib module** I use firebase libraries:

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
}
```

In this situation project compiles but I got the message:

```
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
```

What is interesting when I copy common-lib firebase dependencies to my app module the message disappear.

**Is it a bug? Did I set something wrong? Is my application output file contains proper 11.2.0 version of firebase libraries or as the messages says 9.0.0 ?**

---

*Edited*

**project build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**app module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    (...)
}


dependencies {

    debugCompile project(path: ':common-lib', configuration: 'debug')
    debugTestCompile project(path: ':common-lib', configuration: 'debugTest')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':common-lib', configuration: 'release')

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**common-lib moudle build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    (...)
}
dependencies {
    (...)
    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Oh, I think you should put it on the common-lib one. Or any that actually have Firebase dependencies

Comment: @cricket_007 When I'm adding  "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" to my common-lib, I get the error: "Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension."

Comment: @AppiDevo Have you tried to see gradle depedency tree using  gradle app:dependencies command?

Comment: Any luck on why this occured? I've had the same issue and I had to add firebase to the app's dependencies to resolve this. I didnt need this in the past but was just upgrading gradle etc and this cropped up

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add this:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the root level of gradle file?

Comment: Yes, I have this at the bottom of the app module build.gradle file (in which I don't have firebase dependencies)

Comment: paste your gradle file in order to be sure

Comment: quote: Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

Comment: It goes in app/build.gradle, not the root one @Appi

Comment: @Vyacheslav I edited the post with my build.gradle file indluded.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I have it in my app/build.gradle file, not in the project root one

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by adding in my `app (main)` module dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
```

So now I have above dependencies in my `app` and in my `common-lib (library)` module.
I also added `$firebase_version` and `$support_version` so maintenance is easier. Variables are placed in the project `gradle.build`:

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        firebase_version = '11.8.0'
        support_version = '26.1.0'
    }
    (...)
}
```

The problem appears because google-services plugin checks dependencies and doesn't find it in the app gradle file. But it doesn't check library dependencies, even if you expose it explicitly by changing **[implementation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)** to **[api](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)**:

common-lib gradle.build:

```
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
```

It still doesn't work.

---

- More about [how apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231761/what-does-apply-plugin-com-google-gms-google-services-do)
- If you migrating to Android Studio 3 and Gradle 4 you can also avoid "*Android dependency '..' has different version for the compile (..) and runtime (..) classpath*" error if you add additional dependencies to your app module. [More about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266071/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime).