# What does _apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'_ do?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, gradle-plugin

What does exactly adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` do? If I comment this, my app still will compile and run. More about adding Firebase to the project [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: It is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads resources out of your google-services.json file as described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).  It also adds a compile dependency on `firebase-core` if not already present.  That dependency will cause [FirebaseInitProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider) to get merged into your manifest, which is responsible for initializing a default [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) at app launch with the resources it read during the build phase.

If you want to learn more about Firebase app init, read:

- [How does Firebase initialize on Android?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html)
- [Take Control of Your Firebase Init on Android](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html)