# Android dependency '..' has different version for the compile (..) and runtime (..) classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I migrated to Android Studio 3 and Gradle 4. Then I changed `compile` to `implementation` in my build.gradle files. But I get the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core' has different version for the compile (9.0.0) and runtime (11.6.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

When I change `implementation` to `api` the error disappear. But this is not the solution. I have the app module and one library module. App build.gradle has only one dependency:

```
implementation project(':common-lib')
```

The `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is correctly placed at the bottom of the app build.gradle file (the project worked before migration to Gradle 4)

Dependencies from gradlew app:dependencies (clipping of text):

Compile

```
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugAndroidTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.0
|         |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.0.0
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0
|              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
|              |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0 (*)
|              |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.0 (*)
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.0.0
|              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
|              |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0 (*)
|              \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0 (*)
\--- project :common-lib
(............)
```

Runtime

```
debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: debugAndroidTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0 -> 11.6.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 26.1.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
|         |    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
|         |    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|         |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.6.0
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.6.0
|         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.6.0
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.0
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.6.0
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.6.0
\--- project :common-lib
(.............)
```

Edited:

app dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common-lib')
}
```

common-lib dependencies

```
dependencies {
    //android firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$firebase_version"
    //android support
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:$support_version"
    //others
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates3:3.0.1'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.1'

    //server
    implementation files('libs/xxx.jar')
    implementation files('libs/yyy.jar')
    implementation files('libs/zzz.jar')

    //tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

versions:

```
ext {
    firebase_version = '11.6.0'
    support_version = '26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: post your *app* dependencies and your *lib* dependencies.

Comment: @Ibrahim posted

Comment: You have included `com.google.firebase:firebase` libs in your *app* dependencies ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It appears that, previously, you were implicitly depending on the common-lib module to export Firebase SDKs to your app module.  Now that you've changed from "compile" to "implementation", you're no longer exporting those SDKs.  So, what's happening now is this: the google-services plugin is adding v9.0.0 of firebase-core to your app module since it no longer sees it present in the visible classpath of your app module.

You should be able to work around this by manually adding firebase-core to your app module at the correct version.  Or, you can continue to export Firebase SDKs from your library module to your app module by switching to an "api" dependency instead of an "implementation" dependency.

Comment: Does `google-services`  plugin add `firebase-core` to app dependency?, It will be the same behavior if i included the `firebase-core` v.9 into the dependencies ?

Comment: That's how it works, yes.  Manually add the correct version to your app to force all versions to match.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

add following code into your your buildscript

```
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "version which should be used - in your case 11.6.0"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Best Regards,

Eddi

Comment: doesnt work, gives a new error "
> Could not get unknown property 'resolutionStrategy' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Answer (score 3):

Changing the version of google-services over the top level gradle file fixed the issue for me. It seems the older version is indirectly injecting the firebase-core versions and updating the firebase version explicitly makes the conflict

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2' // Just updated the version here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion to 28 and I also faced this same error.

I upgraded all the dependencies version in app.gradle to 28.0.0 and also in project .gradle file upgraded com.android.tools.build:gradle to 3.3.2

i.e  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

After this project synced successfully

Answer (score 0):

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

put this code in your project gradle