# Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' has different version for the compile (27.1.1) and runtime (28.0.0)

Tags: android, gradle

`Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' has different version for the compile (27.1.1) and runtime (28.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution`

Getting this error while building my android app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android dependency '..' has different version for the compile (..) and runtime (..) classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266071/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

In your **project** `build.gradle` file, add below in the end:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```